# Man awakes, thinks he's on a strange planet but is really on future Earth

Tags: story-identification

I need help finding  a book about a guy who wakes up to a world that he assumes to be a different planet. He eventually makes a tree house and then finds a girl who looks human but has a flap of skin on her toe.

He later find out he is on Earth but in a distant future where nuclear war mutated humans into different species and all technology is eliminated, hence their primitive lifestyle.

Comment: Why didn't he realise it was Earth?

Comment: _[Planet of the Apes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes)_?

Comment: Were there damn dirty apes? Did they put their stinking paws on him?

Comment: @Valorum Heh. Beatcha. And now I see there are several recent questions about this very franchise. So, more likely an effect of those.

Comment: *[The Transall Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transall_Saga)*?